# eclipse plugin: is it possible to "listen" and interpret double-clicks on text editor?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

The big picture is that we need to implement a remote debugger as an eclipse plugin. The code that will be passed by during debugging will be shown in an text editor.

I am thinking how can we deal with the issue of placing breakpoints on a file. Is there any way that I can listen for a double-click event and then get the specific line on which the double click was issued?

Many thanks for reading and giving it a thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [Eclipse Debug project](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/debug/index.php) - they have the complete infrastructure for a new debugger. Including interfaces to breakpoints, editors, etc..

Comment: Thanks a lot. A bulls eye type of response. Highly appreciated